# Batch script not setting variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, set

I have (2) text files that a batch script will open, read line 2 and set a variable to the value of line 2. The text files only contain 3 lines, the first file is numbers, the second is letters. I am using the following to open, read and set:

```
for /f "token=1*delim=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" chnid.txt') do if %%G equ 2 set xcid=%%H
for /f "token=1*delim=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" cfile.txt') do if %%L equ 2 set xcfile=%%J
```

When executed it works great on setting xcid for the number but it never sets xcfile for the letters. During execution, I can see that it steps thru each line of the text file with the if  statement and it shows the value of each line but it never sets the variable.

The chnid file has 3 lines with a group of numbers one each line:

```
48051
12547
89745
```

The cfile file has 3 lines with a group of letters on each line:

```
"abcdef"
"ghijkl"
"mnopqr"
```

Can anybody suggest whey it won't set the `xcfile` variable = `%%J`?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you want

```
 set xcfile=%%M
```

Answer (score 0):

2 basic reasons.

First, "2" is not contained in the file you are targeting.

Second, In normal alphabets, `L` is followed by `M`, not `J`. That may of course not be politically correct, as it probably offends dyslexics, so I may be out-of-date, but I reckon it's very likely to be a cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, the change to M was the solution.

Comment: Magoo, You missed the findstr in the command that is numbering the lines, hence 2 is in both sets.